# #ifdef with gfortran 77

Tags: debugging, preprocessor, fortran77, conditional-compilation

I am using gfortran to compile FORTRAN 77 and would like to have DEBUG build options by using the preprocessor directive #ifdef.  However, when I use them I get compile time warnings "Illegal preprocessor directive".  Is it possible to have this functionality without deviating from the standard toolchain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The c preprocessor can be used on the FORTRAN code for this purpose.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Preprocessing-Options.html

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this issue by adding `-xf77-cpp-input` to my command-line options to `gfortran`, i.e.:

```
$ gfortran -xf77-cpp-input -c -g -DDEBUG fortfile.f
```